# Arduino Uno I2C two sensor connection Issues

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I have been working on trying to get the MAXREFDES#117 PPG and the LIS3DH Accelerometer to run together. I am modifying the sample code found here to do so:

https://github.com/MaximIntegratedRefDesTeam/RD117_ARDUINO

However, when I add the line lis.begin(0x18) to the PPG code the code stops running correctly. There is no error and the only thing that will print to the Serial Monitor is “LIS”. I have gotten the accelerometer to run using acceldemo and the PPG sensor running using the code from GitHub (above), so I do not think it is a connection issue. I am not quite sure what the problem is and would greatly appreciate help.

```
//PPG

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "algorithm.h"
#include "max30102.h"

//Accelerometer

#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_LIS3DH.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>

#define MAX_BRIGHTNESS 255

#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_UNO)
//Arduino Uno doesn't have enough SRAM to store 100 samples of IR led data and red led data in 32-bit format
//To solve this problem, 16-bit MSB of the sampled data will be truncated.  Samples become 16-bit data.
uint16_t aun_ir_buffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint16_t aun_red_buffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#else
uint32_t aun_ir_buffer[100]; //infrared LED sensor data
uint32_t aun_red_buffer[100];  //red LED sensor data
#endif
int32_t n_ir_buffer_length; //data length
int32_t n_spo2;  //SPO2 value
int8_t ch_spo2_valid;  //indicator to show if the SPO2 calculation is valid
int32_t n_heart_rate; //heart rate value
int8_t  ch_hr_valid;  //indicator to show if the heart rate calculation is valid
uint8_t uch_dummy;

 

Adafruit_LIS3DH lis = Adafruit_LIS3DH();


// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
   // initialize serial communication at 115200 bits per second:
   Serial.begin(115200);
   while (!Serial) delay(10);     // will pause Zero, Leonardo, etc until      serial console open

   Serial.println("LIS3DH initializing");
   lis.begin(0x18);
   Serial.println("LIS3DH initialized!");

   maxim_max30102_reset(); //resets the MAX30102
   pinMode(10, INPUT);  //pin D10 connects to the interrupt output pin of the MAX30102

   delay(1000);
   maxim_max30102_read_reg(REG_INTR_STATUS_1,&uch_dummy);  //Reads/clears  the interrupt status register

   while(Serial.available()==0)  //wait until user presses a key
   {

      Serial.write(27);       // ESC command
      Serial.print(F("[2J"));    // clear screen command
      Serial.println(F("Press any key to start conversion"));
      delay(1000);

   }

   uch_dummy=Serial.read();
   maxim_max30102_init();  //initialize the MAX30102
}

 

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:

void loop() {
  uint32_t un_min, un_max, un_prev_data, un_brightness;  //variables to calculate the on-board LED brightness that reflects the heartbeats
  int32_t i;
  float f_temp;
  
  un_brightness=0;
  un_min=0x3FFFF;
  un_max=0;
  
  n_ir_buffer_length=100;  //buffer length of 100 stores 4 seconds of samples running at 25sps

  //read the first 100 samples, and determine the signal range
  for(i=0;i<n_ir_buffer_length;i++)
  {
    while(digitalRead(10)==1);  //wait until the interrupt pin asserts
    maxim_max30102_read_fifo((aun_red_buffer+i), (aun_ir_buffer+i));  //read from MAX30102 FIFO
    
    if(un_min>aun_red_buffer[i])
      un_min=aun_red_buffer[i];  //update signal min
    if(un_max<aun_red_buffer[i])
      un_max=aun_red_buffer[i];  //update signal max
    Serial.print(F("red="));
    Serial.print(aun_red_buffer[i], DEC);
    Serial.print(F(", ir="));
    Serial.println(aun_ir_buffer[i], DEC);
  }
  
  un_prev_data=aun_red_buffer[i];

  //calculate heart rate and SpO2 after first 100 samples (first 4 seconds of samples)
  maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(aun_ir_buffer, n_ir_buffer_length, aun_red_buffer, &n_spo2, &ch_spo2_valid, &n_heart_rate, &ch_hr_valid); 
  
  //Continuously taking samples from MAX30102.  Heart rate and SpO2 are calculated every 1 second
  while(1)
  {
    i=0;
    un_min=0x3FFFF;
    un_max=0;

    //dumping the first 25 sets of samples in the memory and shift the last 75 sets of samples to the top
    for(i=25;i<100;i++)
    {
      aun_red_buffer[i-25]=aun_red_buffer[i];
      aun_ir_buffer[i-25]=aun_ir_buffer[i];

      //update the signal min and max
      if(un_min>aun_red_buffer[i])
        un_min=aun_red_buffer[i];
      if(un_max<aun_red_buffer[i])
        un_max=aun_red_buffer[i];
    }

    //take 25 sets of samples before calculating the heart rate.
    for(i=75;i<100;i++)
    {
      un_prev_data=aun_red_buffer[i-1];
      while(digitalRead(10)==1);
      digitalWrite(9, !digitalRead(9));
      maxim_max30102_read_fifo((aun_red_buffer+i), (aun_ir_buffer+i));

      //calculate the brightness of the LED
      if(aun_red_buffer[i]>un_prev_data)
      {
        f_temp=aun_red_buffer[i]-un_prev_data;
        f_temp/=(un_max-un_min);
        f_temp*=MAX_BRIGHTNESS;
        f_temp=un_brightness-f_temp;
        if(f_temp<0)
          un_brightness=0;
        else
          un_brightness=(int)f_temp;
      }
      else
      {
        f_temp=un_prev_data-aun_red_buffer[i];
        f_temp/=(un_max-un_min);
        f_temp*=MAX_BRIGHTNESS;
        un_brightness+=(int)f_temp;
        if(un_brightness>MAX_BRIGHTNESS)
          un_brightness=MAX_BRIGHTNESS;
      }
#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_LILYPAD_USB)  
      analogWrite(13, un_brightness);
#endif

#if defined(ARDUINO_AVR_FLORA8)
      LED.setPixelColor(0, un_brightness/BRIGHTNESS_DIVISOR, 0, 0);
      LED.show();
#endif

      //send samples and calculation result to terminal program through UART
      Serial.print(F("red="));
      Serial.print(aun_red_buffer[i], DEC);
      Serial.print(F(", ir="));
      Serial.print(aun_ir_buffer[i], DEC);
      
      Serial.print(F(", HR="));
      Serial.print(n_heart_rate, DEC);
      
      Serial.print(F(", HRvalid="));
      Serial.print(ch_hr_valid, DEC);
      
      Serial.print(F(", SPO2="));
      Serial.print(n_spo2, DEC);

      Serial.print(F(", SPO2Valid="));
      Serial.println(ch_spo2_valid, DEC);
    }
    maxim_heart_rate_and_oxygen_saturation(aun_ir_buffer, n_ir_buffer_length, aun_red_buffer, &n_spo2, &ch_spo2_valid, &n_heart_rate, &ch_hr_valid); 
  }
}
```

Here is a picture of how the two sensors are wired:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may find that if you `Serial.flush();` after the message, but before the `lis.begin()`, that the entire message makes it out through serial and *then* it locks up.  I'm interested to know how it's wired.  You should run the [I2C scanner](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner/) and see if it doesn't also lock up in that as well, in which case you can at least temporarily not be concerned about your project or accelerator specific code.

Comment: Serial.flush(); did fix that line of output. I ran the I2C_Scanner and it picked up two sensors (0x18 and 0x57). Do you think that there is an issue with the wiring then? Before running the code with the combined sensors, I run the code for just the PPG and just the accelerometer to make sure both are wired correctly.

Comment: You need to solder those connections.  Otherwise you're going to go insane debugging this.